# Minecraft: How do I tp to a player's last location?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to teleport to the location another player was when they left the game. How do I do that when they are not online?

Thanks!

Comment: This smells like griefing plans…

Answer (score 0):

A method that comes to mind is to summon armor stands at the player and summon some sort of tp marker when they leave.

Try these three commands:

execute as @e[type=armor_stand,name=track] at @s unless entity @a[distance=..1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:true,CustomName:"\"tp marker\""}
/kill @e[type=armor_stand,name=track]
execute as @a at @s run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invulnerable:true,CustomName:"\"track\"",Invisible:true,Marker:true}

That should track all the players and summon a tp marker when they leave. Let me know if it doesn't work/you're having troubles.

Comment: Way too complicated. Just use `teleport @e[type=armor_stand,tag=<whatever>] <player_name>`. Then you teleport to that armour stand, at least if the chunk is loaded.

Comment: My method above doesn't require any pre-setup, ie summoning those teleporting armor stands. Also, teleporting doesn't work very well when detecting players because it will lag behind the player.

Comment: Another reason is because we'd have to teleport that armor stand to the nearest player, so there is a chance it will start teleporting to a different player if a player crosses path with another one, and if a player leaves it might start teleporting to players who get to close to the marker.

Comment: It does indeed require summoning an armour stand. You even do it every tick, which creates a lot of lag. And summoning something at a player's position and teleporting to it both have the same amount of lag, which is 0-0.05 seconds (plus network, performance stuff, etc.). And the problem only exists if you use `@p` instead of a player name. That can be solved with scoreboards, tags or anything else, which depends on the circumstances. The asker didn't specify them. Also, I'm pretty sure it will be used for griefing, so maybe we shouldn't put too much effort into this. ;)

Comment: Hmm, I guess you're right about the griefing, which makes sense to use player names. Man you're smart :D